# Laravel Redis display sock data with vue

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I built a simple event class with laravel, which I fire if one sents a notifications the event class looks like this:

```
class InquirySent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $inquiries;

    public function __construct($inquiries)
    {
        $this->inquiries = $inquiries;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['inquiry-sent-channel'];
    }
}
```

I fire the event (create a new instance) like this:

```
    # fire inquiry notification event
    event(new InquirySent(
        $user->notifications()->where('type', InvoiceInquiry::class)->count()
    ));
```

I set up my node server with this script:

```
var server = require('http').Server();

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// class declaration
var Redis = require('ioredis');

/**
 * Redis UserSignedUp Channel
 */
var redisSignedUp = new Redis();

redisSignedUp.subscribe('signed-up-channel');

/**
 * Redis InquirySent Channel
 */
var redisInquirySent = new Redis();

redisInquirySent.subscribe('inquiry-sent-channel');

redisInquirySent.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message.data.inquiries);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data.inquiries);
});

// run server on port X
server.listen(3000);
```

And in my event.js I bind it like this:

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.3.115:3000');

new Vue({

    el: '#app',

   data: {
       inquiries: [],
   },

   ready: function() {
       // InquirySent event
       socket.on('inquiry-sent-channel:App\\Events\\InquirySent', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           this.inquiries.push(data);
       }.bind(this));
   }

});
```

The console (command line) returns the correct value in my case: 69

but if I try to put it in my view with vue.js it does not display anything, nor do I get any errors in the browser console:

```
<li v-for="inquiry in inquiries">@{{ inquiry }}</li>
```